# Apache HTTP server redirect to port 8085 IF url contains "demo" ELSE redirect to port 8080

Tags: apache, redirect, routes, httpd.conf

I have 2 applications running on port 8080 and 8085. Both has different URL queries/paths and application on port 8085 have keyword **demo** on all of its URL queries/paths and other doesn't. So it acts as an unique identifier

Can I make any change to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file so that if the server identifies **demo** as the keyword then request will reach application on port 8085, if not then request will reach port application on port 8080 ?

If there is a way, please provide sample configuration which goes into httpd.conf file

**EDIT 1:**

After trying from first 2 of below answers, I couldn't achieve this. I don't know if ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse are not allowing to achieve this. I tried commenting them, adding them in VirtualHost etc. But did not help.

This is the flow we are expecting:
User will hit URL (without mentioning port) like - `https://example.com/demo` and this will be routed to app on port `8085` else routed to `8080`

May be taking look at my complete httpd.conf might help

Link to my httpd.conf - https://gofile.io/d/tWIHvX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: self answer after being able to achieve this

Achieved this using `LocationMatch` directive easily. Below is the configuration.

As this is regex dependent you can change to check conditions like ends with, starts with, contains and etc. And both the below LocationMatch conditions are in my httpd.conf

1.If URL `like 192.168.1.113/demo` then go to 8085

```
<LocationMatch "^/(demo)(.*)$">
  RewriteEngine on
  ProxyPass         http://localhost:8085/ nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:8085/
</LocationMatch>
```

2.If URL `not like 192.168.1.113/demo` then go to 8080

```
<LocationMatch "^/((?!demo).)*$">
  RewriteEngine on
  ProxyPass         http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
  ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:8080/
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Does this work for https as well? or just for http?

Comment: it works for both http and https

Comment: Can we retain the ipaddress instead of localhost?

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by retain. But if you meant if we can use ip address instead of localhost then, yes we can

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite Condition if the query string contains a word "demo":

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>          
    <Directory /var/www/example/>
        Allow From All
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^8085$
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (demo)
        RewriteRule ^Demo http://%{HTTP_HOST}:%{SERVER_PORT}/$1 [L,R]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Rewrite condition if the query string does not contain the word "demo":

```
<VirtualHost *:8085>          
    <Directory /var/www/example/>
        Allow From All
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (!demo)
        RewriteRule ^Demo http://%{HTTP_HOST}:%{SERVER_PORT}/$1 [L,R]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

if the SERVER_PORT doesn't work, please try the port directly like below:

```
RewriteRule ^Demo http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8085/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: thanks I will try this and accept it soon if it works.
can you tell me if I should be bothered about `/var/www/example/` ?

Comment: you dont have to be bothered about /var/www/example since the HTTP_HOST will pick the folder automatically as per the configuration.

Comment: Tried this but couldn't achieve this. Attached `httpd.conf` that I have. May be if it helps in someway

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
#some conf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} demo [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} demo
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8085%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
#some more conf
</VirtualHost>
```

**OR**

```
<VirtualHost *:8085>
#some conf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !demo
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !demo
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
#some more conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Tried this but couldn't achieve this. Attached `httpd.conf` that I have. May be if it helps in someway